# HTML 5 with CSS 3 and HTML 5 sockets

Tags: sockets, html

Does any body know where to get the tutorials for this? Because I have searched in the google and I could not find proper source. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Tutorials are rather thin on the ground at the moment. HTML 5 and CSS 3 are both in draft form only, are subject to change, and have very poor support in browsers.

The HTML 5 spec is at http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/
The CSS 3 specs are at http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work
The HTML 5 web sockets spec is at http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/

Answer (score 0):

http://ajaxian.com/archives/legitimizing-comet-with-html-5-websocket has an example of this. The show creating,opening,reading and closing the socket.